# Differential of a vector field

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How is the derivative of a vector field defined? Gradient only works on scalar fields, divergence or rotation is not what I am looking for.

Let's take an easy example:
$f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2 $, $f(x,y) =   \begin{pmatrix}
        \sin(y)  \\
        x \cos(y) \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

How can I illustrate the linear map $Df(x,y)$ ? Is it the matrix $  \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & \cos(y)  \\
        \cos(y) & -x\sin(y)  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$
?

Answer (score 0):

If $ \mathbf x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ and $\mathbf f = (f_1, \dots, f_m)$ we can define the Jacobian matrix, tha is a "generalization" of gradient for vector field:

$$J \, \mathbf f = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}  \end{bmatrix}\qquad \operatorname (J \, \mathbf f)_{ij} = \frac{\partial f_i (\mathbf {x})}{\partial x_j} $$

Your intuition is correct.